# Multiple Search Bar Options in Leaflet

Tags: r, vector, leaflet

I have this map in leaflet/r:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(dplyr)

# using the same reproducible data from the question/example
cities <- na.omit(read.csv(
    textConnection("City,Lat,Long,Pop, term1, term2
                    Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966, AAA, BBB
                    Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017, CCC, DDD
                    New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000, EEE, FFF
                    Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000, GGG, HHH
                    Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841, III, JJJ
                    Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994, JJJ, LLL
                    ")))

# leaf-green.png
#https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png


leaflet(cities) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
    addMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
                    addResetMapButton() %>%
                    # these markers will be "invisible" on the map:
                    addMarkers(
                        data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, label = cities$City,
                        group = 'cities', # this is the group to use in addSearchFeatures()
                        # make custom icon that is so small you can't see it:
                        icon = makeIcon(
                            iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
                            iconWidth = 1, iconHeight = 1
                        )
                    ) %>%
                    addSearchFeatures(
                        targetGroups = 'cities', # group should match addMarkers() group
                        options = searchFeaturesOptions(
                            zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
                            autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE
                        )
                    )
```

Using this map, I am able to "search" for a city using the search bar:

[image]

**I would like to modify this code so that I can search based on "city", "term1" or "term2".**

I tried this code over here:

```
leaflet(cities) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
    addMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
                    addResetMapButton() %>%
                    # these markers will be "invisible" on the map:
                    addMarkers(
                        data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, label = cities$City,
                        group = 'cities', # this is the group to use in addSearchFeatures()
                        # make custom icon that is so small you can't see it:
                        icon = makeIcon(
                            iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
                            iconWidth = 1, iconHeight = 1
                        )
                    ) %>%
                    addSearchFeatures(
                        targetGroups = c('cities', 'term1', 'term2'), # group should match addMarkers() group
                        options = searchFeaturesOptions(
                            zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
                            autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE
                        )
                    )
```

This code runs without error, but I can not search using "term1" or "term2":

[image]

According to the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet.extras/versions/1.0.0/topics/addSearchFeatures), "addSearchFeatures" should accept a "vector of group names of groups whose features need to be searched". I was under the impression that vectors in R are specified using `c('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')`  - but apparently in this function, this is not the case?

- Could someone please show me how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the element to be a search term in `addSearchFeatures`, I'm pretty sure that it has to be a `group` element. Check it out:

```
leaflet(cities) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addResetMapButton() %>%
  # these markers will be "invisible" on the map:
  addMarkers(
    data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, label = cities$City,
    group = 'cities',# this is the group to use in addSearchFeatures()
    # make custom icon that is so small you can't see it:
    icon = makeIcon(
      iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
      iconWidth = 1, iconHeight = 1
    )) %>%
  addMarkers(data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, 
             label = cities$term1, group = 'term1') %>% 
  addMarkers(data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, 
             label = cities$term2, group = 'term2') %>% 
  addSearchFeatures(
    targetGroups = c('cities', 'term1', 'term2'), # group should match addMarkers() group
    options = searchFeaturesOptions(
      zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
      autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Just one question I had: In the code I posted, when you launch the map - when you zoom in and zoom out, the "blue pins" will "collapse" into the "green circles". In your code, the blue pins and the green circles wont collapse into each other. Is there a way to change this? Thank you so much for everything!

Comment: I created a new post that addresses this question in case you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73765486/customizing-leaflet-map-icons-in-r . Thank you so much all your help Kat!